# How to optimize SQL query with MIN MAX function

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance

This is my query

```
SELECT
    [Car].CarId AS Id,
    CAST(MIN(ISNULL([Dates].StartDate, [Reco].InsStartDate)) AS date) AS StartDate,
    CAST(MAX(ISNULL([Dates].EndDate, [Reco].InsEndDate)) AS date) AS EndDate
FROM
    dbo.TabReco [Reco]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Insurance [INS] ON [INS].InsId = [Reco].InsId
    INNER JOIN dbo.InsuranceCar [Details] ON [Details].INSCarId = [INS].INSCarId
    INNER JOIN dbo.CarHistory [Car] ON [Car].CarHistId = [Details].CarHistId
    INNER JOIN dbo.InsuranceRiskDates [Dates] ON [Dates].INSId = [INS].INSId
GROUP BY
    [Reco].Number,
    [Car].CarId
```

When I run this query it takes a lot time. The problem is with part MIN/MAX for dates.

```
CAST(MIN(ISNULL([Dates].StartDate, [Reco].InsStartDate)) AS date) AS StartDate,
CAST(MAX(ISNULL([Dates].EndDate, [Reco].InsEndDate)) AS date) AS EndDate
```

If I remove that part, then query works faster. Is there any way to optimize such a query? Or it's impossible.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan? Without some kind of details we are just guessing.

Comment: If you have indexes on the keys used for the `join`, there is little you can do.

Comment: If your dates were stored *as DATE* then you might be able to add some clever indexes to fix this.  Since they are not, the best you can do is probably a covering index, which may or may not help.  Either way we'd still need to see a query plan.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need ISNULL when you are using INNER JOIN.

Don't bother with that, just remove that part.

except if you allow null on [Dates].StartDate and [Dates].EndDate 
or if you use LEFT JOIN :

```
SELECT
    [Car].CarId AS Id,
    CAST(MIN(ISNULL([Dates].StartDate, [Reco].InsStartDate)) AS date) AS StartDate,
    CAST(MAX(ISNULL([Dates].EndDate, [Reco].InsEndDate)) AS date) AS EndDate
FROM
    dbo.TabReco [Reco]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Insurance [INS] ON [INS].InsId = [Reco].InsId
    INNER JOIN dbo.InsuranceCar [Details] ON [Details].INSCarId = [INS].INSCarId
    INNER JOIN dbo.CarHistory [Car] ON [Car].CarHistId = [Details].CarHistId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.InsuranceRiskDates [Dates] ON [Dates].INSId = [INS].INSId
GROUP BY
    [Reco].Number,
    [Car].CarId
```

you may need index for each column in the join area which is not primary key.

Edited : I have an idea besides indexing, try this :

```
SELECT Id,
CAST(MIN(StartDate) AS date) AS StartDate,
CAST(MIN(EndDate) AS date) AS EndDate
FROM
( 
    SELECT [Reco].Number,
    [Car].CarId AS Id,
    [Dates].StartDate, [Dates].EndDate
    FROM
    dbo.TabReco [Reco]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Insurance [INS] ON [INS].InsId = [Reco].InsId
    INNER JOIN dbo.InsuranceCar [Details] ON [Details].INSCarId = [INS].INSCarId
    INNER JOIN dbo.CarHistory [Car] ON [Car].CarHistId = [Details].CarHistId
    INNER JOIN dbo.InsuranceRiskDates [Dates] ON [Dates].INSId = [INS].INSId
    WHERE [Dates].StartDate IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Reco].Number,
    [Car].CarId AS Id,
    [Reco].InsStartDate AS StartDate, 
    [Reco].InsEndDate AS EndDate
    FROM
    dbo.TabReco [Reco]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Insurance [INS] ON [INS].InsId = [Reco].InsId
    INNER JOIN dbo.InsuranceCar [Details] ON [Details].INSCarId = [INS].INSCarId
    INNER JOIN dbo.CarHistory [Car] ON [Car].CarHistId = [Details].CarHistId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.InsuranceRiskDates [Dates] ON [Dates].INSId = [INS].INSId
    WHERE [Dates].StartDate IS NULL
) x
GROUP BY Number, Id
```

Comment: ISNULL is not a problem, the problem is with MIN MAX, because there are thousands records